# Can subliminal affirmations really use the subconscious mind to naturally reshape your nose?

Tags: physiology, unconscious

My reflexive response to this is no, however, I have noticed two different phenomenon which begs to re-assess.

(Please see and read video description and some comments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anMDt7Ofda8)

Firstly, in my work, I have met some adults with severe debilitating mental special needs. The ones that peaked my re-assessment on this subject, were ones who as young children, were only considered slightly "slow" but physically did not look different than their peers. Then around a certain age (one at 7 for example), went through a terrible reaction like massive seizures or food poisoning, making them ***loose all mental facilities,*** permanently. Now, at a much older age, their facial features are completely altered to what we associate ***some*** severely mentally debilitated people with. I prefer not to describe if possible, the point is the actual bone structure and other features seem to have shaped very differently now. However, they were not born that way and the only thing that changed was mind and brain function.

Secondly, there seems to be a staggering number of people online and especially on YouTube, bewildered and [claiming that subliminal programing videos](https://www.google.com/search?q=desired%20face%20subliminal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) have allowed them to change their facial features. With this large sample population (even if half were fake), I think it merits some sort of assessment.

**Can one use their subconscious in some fashion to change the shape of something on their body?**

Comment: Hi @R.B. And Welcome to Cognitive Science, your question received 3 votes to be closed... to me it was an interesting question and i tried to improve it...let me know if that's ok for you...

Comment: extreme emotional deprivation or stress can affect the physiological growth see [psychosocial dwarfism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychosocial_short_stature) at wiki

Comment: @fil hi, thanks, yes it looks good. To put it more clear, another way to ask would be can facial and bodily features be altered without plastic surgery using the the mind and if yes, to what degree ? " For example, is this claim true: "These subliminal affirmations use the power of your subconscious mind to naturally reshape and reconstruct your nose to be exactly as you desire": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anMDt7Ofda8

Comment: @designeranalyst: very interesting, hard to imagine why this couldn't apply to other parts of the body...